# link to path outside of localhost folder using href

Tags: php

### Problem:

localhost folder is: D:\my_files\project\public

Web Server:          Apache HTTP Server

so when I type http://localhost, it goes to D:\my_files\project\public

Structure:

/my_files/project/public/index.php

/my_files/project/src/tech.php

What I want:

<a href="/../src/tech/tech.php">Tech</a>

When clicking the link above it should take me to out of localhost folder inside src folder.

Comment: Hello @Cyborg2030, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide more information on your problem. A simple `Problem: ( and then code )` doesn't make out the point. Also make sure to read [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and re-edit your question.

Comment: Also, you have an extra folder name named `tech` that doesn't exist in your given path above `/my_files/project/src/tech.php`.

Comment: You can not get access to anything above the document root folder via HTTP, that is kinda the point of having a document root.

Comment: What you can do is having a file under the document root that includes the PHP files you want to execute outside. PHP can read and execute files outside of the document root, but the browser can't. That's how the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) works. You only have one php file under the document root that decides what should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access your folder like this since it is not in the Localhost folder. You have two solutions

1. Change Localhost default folder to the parent folder:

> myfiles/project

2. Copy you test.php file to your current localhost folder, with all his dependiencies